# Find correlation/covariance of two distributions with shared marginal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance, correlation

I have two distributions which represent the sum of smaller distributions.

Say distribution `X` is made up of distributions `a`, `b` and `c`: $\mu_a$ = 10, $\sigma_a$ = 3; $\mu_b$ = 15, $\sigma_b$ = 5; $\mu_c$ = 20, $\sigma_c$ = 4; so $\mu_X$ = 45 and $\sigma_X$ = $\sqrt{50}$.

Distribution `Y` is made up of `a`, `d` and `e`: $\mu_a$ = 10, $\sigma_a$ = 3 (this is of course the same as the `a` above); $\mu_d$ = 18, $\sigma_d$ = 2; $\mu_e$ = 12, $\sigma_e$ = 4; so $\mu_X$ = 40 and $\sigma_X$ = $\sqrt{29}$.

With this information, is there a way that I can find the correlation/covariance between the two distributions? Would it have to do with how much `a` contributes to `X` and `Y`'s means and/or variances?

Comment: Only by knowing how $a,b,c,d,e$ are correlated.  In textbook problems they are *usually* asserted to be pairwise independent; are they here?

Comment: @GrahamKemp I intended for them to be independent, although it would be interesting to see how the answer would change if `a` and `b` or any of my example variables were correlated.